# Application crashes if used on secure wifi network

Tags: android, crash, wifi

I have created an application for android 4.0 and above. My application uses internet in almost all stages. Inside each and every activity, I have done all the required handling to check internet connectivity before communicating with the server.

**The problem which I am facing is that, the application is running fine if used on 2G or 3G networks, but it crashes if it is used in a secure wifi connection. I have tried using the application in insecure wifi network where it worked fine.**

The **manifest file** of the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ica.bankpoexamination2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.TakeTestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.PracticeTestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.SpeedTestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.ExamActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.GeneralInstructionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.RateUsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.SpeedTestExamDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.PracticeTestExamDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.ChooseTestTypeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.ExamNamesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.ReportActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.CurrentUpdateActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.TipsAndTricksActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.bankpoexamination2.LibraryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.reportinnactivities.ReportListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.reportinnactivities.ReportDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.reportinnactivities.ReportScoreCardActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.reportinnactivities.ReportTimeManagementActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.reportinnactivities.ReportQuestionReportActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.reportinnactivities.ReportDifficultyLevelActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.reportinnactivities.ReportAllTestReportActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.userregistration.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.userregistration.OtpRegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ica.currentupdate.CurrentUpdateDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**What should I do to fix this?**

P.S: Other applications are working fine on the same secured wifi network.

Comment: stacktrace from logcat please?

Comment: It happens when I am testing on device, logcat is not available for device..........wifi can not be connected from emulator

Comment: Logcat is available from device too. If you can't connect to your PC use tools like aLogcat or integrate libraries like ACRA.

Comment: ok ill do that and post the logcat soon